# SwiftUI Simplify .onChange Modifier for Many TextFields

Tags: ios, xcode, swiftui

I'm searching for a way to simplify/refactor the addition of .onChange(of:) in a SwiftUI
view that has MANY TextFields. If a solution were concise, I would also move the modifier
closer to the  appropriate field rather than at the end of, say, a ScrollView. In this
case, all of the .onChange modifiers call the same function.

Example:

```
.onChange(of: patientDetailVM.pubFirstName) { x in
    changeBackButton()
}
.onChange(of: patientDetailVM.pubLastName) { x in
    changeBackButton()
}
// ten+ more times for other fields
```

I tried "oring" the fields. This does not work:

```
.onChange(of:
            patientDetailVM.pubFirstName ||
            patientDetailVM.pubLastName
) { x in
    changeBackButton()
}
```

This is the simple function that I want to call:

```
func changeBackButton() {
    withAnimation {
        showBackButton = false
        isEditing = true
    }
}
```

Any guidance would be appreciated. Xcode 13.2.1 iOS 15

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Overview of Solution

We extend the `Binding` type, to create two new methods, both of which are called `onChange`.

Both `onChange` methods are intended to be used in situations in which you need to perform some work whenever the `Binding` instance's `wrappedValue` property is **changed** (not just *set*) via its `set` method.

The first `onChange` method **doesn't** pass the new value of the `Binding` instance's `wrappedValue` property to the provided on-change callback method, whereas the second `onChange` method **does** provide it with the new value.

The first `onChange` method allows us to refactor this:

```swift
bindingToProperty.onChange { _ in
    changeBackButton()
}
```

to this:

```swift
bindingToProperty.onChange(perform: changeBackButton)
```

### Solution

#### Helper-Code

```swift
import SwiftUI

extension Binding {
    public func onChange(perform action: @escaping () -> Void) -> Self where Value : Equatable {
        .init(
            get: {
                self.wrappedValue
            },
            set: { newValue in
                guard self.wrappedValue != newValue else { return }
                
                self.wrappedValue = newValue
                action()
            }
        )
    }
    
    public func onChange(perform action: @escaping (_ newValue: Value) -> Void) -> Self where Value : Equatable {
        .init(
            get: {
                self.wrappedValue
            },
            set: { newValue in
                guard self.wrappedValue != newValue else { return }
                
                self.wrappedValue = newValue
                action(newValue)
            }
        )
    }
}
```

#### Usage

```swift
struct EmployeeForm: View {
    @ObservedObject var vm: VM
    
    private func changeBackButton() {
        print("changeBackButton method was called.")
    }
    
    private func occupationWasChanged() {
        print("occupationWasChanged method was called.")
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        Form {
            TextField("First Name", text: $vm.firstName.onChange(perform: changeBackButton))
            TextField("Last Name", text: $vm.lastName.onChange(perform: changeBackButton))
            TextField("Occupation", text: $vm.occupation.onChange(perform: occupationWasChanged))
        }
    }
}

struct Person {
    var firstName: String
    var surname: String
    var jobTitle: String
}

extension EmployeeForm {
    class VM: ObservableObject {
        @Published var firstName = ""
        @Published var lastName = ""
        @Published var occupation = ""
        
        func load(from person: Person) {
            firstName = person.firstName
            lastName = person.surname
            occupation = person.jobTitle
        }
    }
}

struct EditEmployee: View {
    @StateObject private var employeeForm = EmployeeForm.VM()
    @State private var isLoading = true
    
    func fetchPerson() -> Person {
        return Person(
            firstName: "John",
            surname: "Smith",
            jobTitle: "Market Analyst"
        )
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        Group {
            if isLoading {
                Text("Loading...")
            } else {
                EmployeeForm(vm: employeeForm)
            }
        }
        .onAppear {
            employeeForm.load(from: fetchPerson())
            isLoading = false
        }
    }
}

struct EditEmployee_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        EditEmployee()
    }
}
```

### Benefits of Solution

1. Both the helper-code and usage-code are simple and kept very minimal.
2. It keeps the onChange-callback **very** close to the place where the `Binding` instance is provided to the TextField/TextEditor/other type.
3. It's **generic**, and is **very versatile**, as it can be used for any `Binding` instance that has a `wrappedValue` property of **any** type that conforms to the `Equatable` protocol.
4. The `Binding` instances that have on-change callbacks, look just like `Binding` instances that don't have on-change callbacks. Consequently, no types to which these `Binding` instances with on-change callbacks are provided, need special modifications to know how to deal with them.
5. The helper-code doesn't involve the creation of any new `View`'s, `@State` properties, `ObservableObject`'s, `EnvironmentKey`'s, `PreferenceKey`'s, or any other types. It simply adds a couple of methods to the existing type called `Binding` - which obviously is a type that would have already been being used in the code...

Comment: Hey Jeremy. I did a simple experiment with TextFields and TextEditors and your solution worked well. I have not converted my app yet - a lot of fields to convert, but I plan to branch git and do so. Thanks again.

Answer (score 10):

Why not just use a computed var?

```
@State private var something: Int = 1
@State private var another: Bool = true
@State private var yetAnother: String = "whatever"

var anyOfMultiple: [String] {[
    something.description,
    another.description,
    yetAnother
]}

var body: some View {
    VStack {
        //
    }
    .onChange(of: anyOfMultiple) { _ in
        //
    }
}
```

Comment: This helped me, i.e. moving the `.onChangeOf` to modify the outer `VStack` instead of the individual button/toggles inside. Thanks!

Comment: Can you make patientDetailVM Equatable and use one onChange that way?

Answer (score 2):

Any time you are duplicating code you want to move it one level down so the same code can be reused.

Here is a solution, the parent view will hold a variable that will know if the "name" as a whole has changes.

```
import SwiftUI
class PatientDetailViewModel: ObservableObject{
    @Published var pubFirstName: String = "John"
    @Published var pubLastName: String = "Smith"
}
struct TrackingChangesView: View {
    @StateObject var vm: PatientDetailViewModel = PatientDetailViewModel()
    ///Variable to know if there is a change
    @State var nameHasChanges: Bool = false
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView{
            NavigationLink("EditView", destination: {
                VStack{
                    TrackingChangesTextFieldView(hasChanges: $nameHasChanges, text: $vm.pubFirstName, titleKey: "first name")
                    TrackingChangesTextFieldView(hasChanges: $nameHasChanges, text: $vm.pubLastName, titleKey: "last name")
                    Button("save", action: {
                        //Once you verify saving the object reset the variable
                        nameHasChanges = false
                    })//Enable button when there are changes
                        .disabled(!nameHasChanges)
                }
                //Or track the single variable here
                .onChange(of: nameHasChanges, perform: {val in
                    //Your method here
                })
                //trigger back button with variable
                .navigationBarBackButtonHidden(nameHasChanges)
            })
            
        }
    }
}
struct TrackingChangesTextFieldView: View {
    //Lets the parent view know that there has been a change
    @Binding var hasChanges: Bool
    @Binding var text: String
    let titleKey: String
    var body: some View {
        TextField(titleKey, text: $text)
            .onChange(of: text, perform: { _ in
                //To keep it from reloading view if already true
                if !hasChanges{
                    hasChanges = true
                }
            })
    }
}
struct TrackingChangesView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        TrackingChangesView()
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. This DOES work. I'm not sure it is a lot simpler, but I will experiment. Again, for others - try this.

Comment: @JohnSF it mostly just looks cleaner and doesn't call the method every time the user types a letter or makes a correction. Also, if you make changes to the look of the text field you only have to make the changes in one `View` vs individual `TextField`s. Also, you maintain less code overall.

Answer (score 2):

Another way you can do this is to make a combined publisher for both `pubFirstName` and `pubLastName`.
Add following function to your `viewModel`

```
var nameChanged: AnyPublisher<Bool, Never> {
        $patientDetailVM.pubFirstName
            .combineLatest($patientDetailVM.pubLastName)
            .map { firstName, lastName in
                if firstName != patientDetailVM.pubFirstName ||
                    lastName != patientDetailVM.pubLastName
                {
                    return true
                } else {
                    return false
                }
            }
            .eraseToAnyPublisher()
    }
```

and listen to `nameChanged` publisher on `onReceive` of your view

```
.onReceive(of: patientDetailVM.nameChanged) { hasNameChanged in
    changeBackButton()
}
```

so you can listen to either first or last name change.
Didn't test the code but just as an idea.

Comment: This looks like an interesting solution, but it does not work as written. I'll play with it a bit.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a fairly DRY approach I came up with. Obviously, once you've written the code that defines the `NameKeyPathPairs` struct, and the extension to `Array`, etc., it's very simple to use.

### Example Usage

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct EmployeeForm: View {
    @ObservedObject var vm: VM

    private let textFieldProps: NameKeyPathPairs<String, ReferenceWritableKeyPath<VM, String>> = [
        "First Name": \.firstName,
        "Last Name": \.lastName,
        "Occupation": \.occupation
    ]

    private func changeBackButton() {
        print("changeBackButton method was called.")
    }

    var body: some View {
        Form {
            ForEach(textFieldProps, id: \.name) { (name, keyPath) in
                TextField(name, text: $vm[dynamicMember: keyPath])
            }
        }
        .onChange(of: textFieldProps.keyPaths.applied(to: vm)) { _ in
            changeBackButton()
        }
    }
}
```

### .onChange Helper Code

```swift
public struct NameKeyPathPairs<Name, KP>: ExpressibleByDictionaryLiteral where Name : ExpressibleByStringLiteral, KP : AnyKeyPath {
    private let data: [Element]
    public init(dictionaryLiteral elements: (Name, KP)...) {
        self.data = elements
    }
    public var names: [Name] {
        map(\.name)
    }
    public var keyPaths: [KP] {
        map(\.keyPath)
    }
}

extension NameKeyPathPairs : Sequence, Collection, RandomAccessCollection {
    public typealias Element = (name: Name, keyPath: KP)
    public typealias Index = Array<Element>.Index
    public var startIndex: Index { data.startIndex }
    public var endIndex: Index { data.endIndex }
    public subscript(position: Index) -> Element { data[position] }
}

extension RandomAccessCollection {
    public func applied<Root, Value>(to root: Root) -> [Value] where Element : KeyPath<Root, Value> {
        map { root[keyPath: $0] }
    }
}
```

### Remaining Code of Example

```swift
struct Person {
    var firstName: String
    var surname: String
    var jobTitle: String
}

extension EmployeeForm {
    class VM: ObservableObject {
        @Published var firstName = ""
        @Published var lastName = ""
        @Published var occupation = ""
        
        func load(from person: Person) {
            firstName = person.firstName
            lastName = person.surname
            occupation = person.jobTitle
        }
    }
}

struct EditEmployee: View {
    @StateObject private var employeeForm = EmployeeForm.VM()
    @State private var isLoading = true
    
    func fetchPerson() -> Person {
        return Person(
            firstName: "John",
            surname: "Smith",
            jobTitle: "Market Analyst"
        )
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        Group {
            if isLoading {
                Text("Loading...")
            } else {
                EmployeeForm(vm: employeeForm)
            }
        }
        .onAppear {
            employeeForm.load(from: fetchPerson())
            isLoading = false
        }
    }
}

struct EditEmployee_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        EditEmployee()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

this solution worked for me:

```swift
@State private var something: Int = 1
@State private var another: Bool = true
@State private var yetAnother: String = "whatever"

// create computed property
var computedValues: String {
    something.description + another.description + yetAnother
}

var body: some View {
    VStack {
        //
    }
    .onChange(of: computedValues) { _ in
        //
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to listen to different types of value and don't need to look at the specific values you can use `Hasher`.

create a computed property

```
var valuesChanged: Int {
   var hasher = Hasher()
   
   hasher.combine(patientDetailVM.pubLastName)
   hasher.combine(patientDetailVM.pubFirstName)
        
   return hasher.finalize()
}
```

and listen to it

```
.onChange(of: valuesChanged) { _ in
   // react to changed properties
}
```