# single onChange(of:) for an ObservableObject changed Published properties

Tags: swift, swiftui, combine

I have an `ObservableObject` that has many published properties.  I would like to be notified when any one of these published properties is modified without specifying which, because there are over 50 properties and I do not want to have to write `.onChange(of: myObservableObject.propertyXX) { v in ... }` for all 50 of them.  Is there a way to specify `.onChange(of...)` that will cover all 50 of them and any future added/deleted published properties?

I looked at the solutions to this question [SwiftUI Simplify .onChange Modifier for Many TextFields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70416299/swiftui-simplify-onchange-modifier-for-many-textfields), but they all require specifying individual members, which requires maintenance, which is what I am trying to avoid.

Example of what I want:

```
class MyObservableObject : ObservableObject {
  @Published var property1 : ...
  @Published var property2 : ...
  ...
  @Published var property50 : ...
}

struct MyView : View {
  @ObservedObject var myObservableObject : MyObservableObject
  var body : some View {
    VStack {
      ...
    }.onAnyChangedPublishedProperty(of: myObservableObject) { // no need to pass-in an argument
      ...
    }
  }
}
```

An alternative would be to specify regex strings to match for property changed, or pass the property label in that changed:

```
.onAnyChangedPublishedProperty(of: myObservableObject, matching: ["property.5"]) { propertyName in
      ...
    }
```

Comment: you wouldn't normally have that many properties in your model object, perhaps you can combine them all into a struct or array of structs? `body` is called when any property changes, there is no need to use `onChange`.

Comment: What does `myObservableObjectListenerRefresh` do?

Comment: @LuLuGaGa It doesn't matter what `myObservableObjectListenerRefresh` does, I just replaced it with ...

Comment: @malhal I am unable to change the original structure of `MyObservableObject`

Comment: @malhal  `body is called when any property changes, there is no need to use onChange` - I still need to know when a change occurs to any of the published properties.  Doing `.onChange(of: myObservableObject) { v in ... }` doesn't work for me when one of its properties is changed.

Comment: @andrewz I am trying to help. This looks like [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem). I am trying to find out what the root problem is.

Comment: @andrewz you'll have to tell us what you want to do when one of its property changes, then we'll know the correct place to implement it.

Comment: I need to notify another object to refresh itself once any of the properties in `myObservableObject` change

Comment: swift and swiftUI are designed to use value types